# Pandas Apply Exception

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I am trying to build a function to give me the most common value in a column and when there is none just skip it or apply np.nan. However .idmax() causes issues on some columns where it is int64 or a string. Any easy way to generate most common value for a column? thanks

```
def df_missing_info(df):
    most_common_value = df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax())
```

Answer (score 1):

Because [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) also sorting Series get first index for maximal counts and add `next` with `iter` for return first value if exist else get default value, here `NaN`:

```
print (df)
   id  pts  x   y
0   1  NaN  a NaN
1   1  NaN  a NaN
2   1  NaN  s NaN
3   2  0.1  a NaN

def df_missing_info(df):
    return df.apply(lambda x: next(iter(x.value_counts().index), np.nan))
    
a = df_missing_info(df)
print (a)
id       1
pts    0.1
x        a
y      NaN
dtype: object
```

Comment: if im reading this correctly... grab a value count for column x then it iterates the value counts then next() takes the first one thus being the first in the value counts index list?

Comment: @Tinkinc - exactly you are right